# drupal image field the image doesn't show?

Tags: entities, media

My drupal site has a content type called Published which has a image field.When I migrate the site from Win2003 server to  CentOS , all the Published node's image field doesn't show. It appears like this:

[image: the image field]

when I click the image name it shows in a now tab.

I had do some google,but no result . someone said the directory sitename/default/files should be set 777

but it is 777.

Any suggestions Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Download raw drupal form [drupal.org](http://drupal.org)  website, then copy `.htaccess` file from it to your root directory.

Comment: Can you tell me why . I have do nothing to the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the **Public file system path** is correct on Drupal. If you go to admin/config/media/file-system and change the file path to the sites/default/files.

**Here Recommended Permissions for Drupal Files and Folders**

- sites/default 750
- sites/default/files (including sub folders & files)   755 or 770 *

Comment: sorry it doesn't work. the Public file system path: sites/default/files. And Temporary directory path: /tmp.
and I set all the permission to 777.